# How can I perform several print tasks in a row with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

Now I need to implement a function of printing different web pages by clicking one "Print" button. At first you will see a webpage with different check boxes, so you can choose the pages you would like to print. And then according to the selection, the selected webpages will be loaded to the different iFrames which is hidden in the current page, and then with below javascript to print them out.

```
jQuery("body").on("click", "#printBtn", function() {

    var print_page_1 = false;
    var print_page_2 = false;
    var print_page_3 = false;

    //if the checkbox is checked, then mark it as "true"
    if(jQuery('input[name=page_1]:checked').val() == "1") {
        print_page_1 = true;
    }
    if(jQuery('input[name=page_2]:checked').val() == "2") {
        print_page_2 = true;
    }    
if(jQuery('input[name=page_3]:checked').val() == "3") {
    print_page_3 = true;
} 

    //print selected pages
    if(print_page_1) {
        jQuery('#loaderFrameOne').load(function(){
            var w = (this.contentWindow || this.contentDocument.defaultView);
            w.print();
        });
        jQuery('#loaderFrameOne').attr("src", "webpage-one-url");
    } else if (print_page_2) {
        jQuery('#loaderFrameTwo').load(function(){
            var w = (this.contentWindow || this.contentDocument.defaultView);
            w.print();
        });
        jQuery('#loaderFrameTwo').attr("src", "webpage-two-url");
    } else if (print_page_3) {
        jQuery('#loaderFrameThree').load(function(){
            var w = (this.contentWindow || this.contentDocument.defaultView);
            w.print();
        });
        jQuery('#loaderFrameThree').attr("src", "webpage-three-url");
    }
});
```

However, my problem is, whenever I click the print button, only one page will be printed (the print page dialog box only appears once) even though i've selected two or three. I wonder if there is any way to perform all print tasks in a row, to make the print page dialog box appears one after another?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used "else if" instead of "if". So, only one will be executed always

Comment: Hi Shankar, thanks for your advice, the problems is fixed somehow. But when I have all three check boxes checked and click the Print button, the performance is not as expected: sometimes only the first and the last print dialog boxes are appeared, sometimes all of them appeared but they are disordered. I guess it is because the script is running all the time and sometimes skip some part of the code? Do you perhaps have some idea of how to fix this?